# Can Neither-Or be used?

Tags: grammaticality, books, neither-nor

My friend was reading the book "The Fault in Our Stars" by John Green and she found what seems to be a grammar mistake. The [following sentence is found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NFvKW.jpg) in the author's note:

> Neither novels or their readers benefit from attempts to divine whether any facts hide inside a story.

Isn't it grammatically correct to say "nor" instead of "or"?

Comment: Yes, it is correct to use _nor_ here. That doesn't necessarily mean it's incorrect to use _or_; some will tell you it is; others that it isn't.

Comment: Both "nor" and "or" is grammatical here. Both are standard usage. There are other threads on this site that are related to your question.

Answer (score 4):

It is generally accepted (or at least suggested) that *neither* should be paired with *nor* and *either* with *or*.

A thorough discussion of this can be found [here](http://www.dailywritingtips.com/neither-or/).
After looking at various sources, the author of the post concludes with

> So, is "neither…or" all right to use? No, not in modern usage.
>
> People who have the leisure and inclination to argue about such things are free to do so. Those who just want to write inoffensive standard English are advised to go with the conventional rule that *either* is used with *or* and *neither* is used with *nor*.

Note well, however, that there seems to be a bit of disagreement on whether or not *neither...or* is acceptable in *some* cases.  The above post quotes Merriam-Webster as stating:

> Although use with *or* is neither archaic nor wrong, the conjunction *neither* is usually followed by *nor*.

Answer (score 0):

Considering that "neither" is a conjunction of "not either," I think "neither...or" is the correct combination.

Would we comment "Not either James nor Bob will be attending?" I ask this rhetorically, of course.

"You will receive neither a signing bonus or six weeks' vacation in your offer package." The "or" preceded by the implied "not" in "neither" seem to combine to make it abundantly clear that not either of the subject matter will be present, etc. without creating double negatives.