# Is it correct to use "his or her" after "Neither Jake nor Janet..."?

Tags: possessive-pronouns, coordinating-conjunctions, anaphora

Is the following sentence grammatically correct:

"Neither Jake nor Janet brought **his or her** homework to class."

I understand that it has recently become acceptable to use a singular *they* for ambiguous gender, but in this situation we can assume Jake is male and Janet is female. Is the sentence formally and grammatically correct as it is? Or should I use a singular *they*? Thank you.

Comment: Neither brought their homework.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a correct gender-neutral singular pronoun ("his" vs. "her" vs. "their")?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/48/is-there-a-correct-gender-neutral-singular-pronoun-his-vs-her-vs-their)

Comment: Many people find "Neither X ***n***or Y" preferable to "Neither X or Y". See [Can Neither-Or be used?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/176941)

Comment: @sumelic Thank you for that reference. It was very informative!

Comment: Glad I could help. I have edited the title of your question and the tags because the phrase "indefinite pronouns" usually refers to pronouns like *someone, somebody, something.* The words *his, her* and *their* are categorized as personal pronouns, even when they don't refer to one particular person.

Comment: If the Q is "Is it correct?" then, yes, it is. I do not see anything ungrammatical about the sentence *per se*.

Comment: SpaceLion, we need to wait a day or two before accepting an answer, so as to allow enough time for members to see and respond to the question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is no perfect way out of your dilemma.  First, you should write “Neither Jake **nor** Janet...”.  Various ways through have been tried.  Of these, “... have brought **their** homework ...” is the most popular, clumsy though it still seems.  Your ‘*his or her* might scrape through, despite the danger of a perceived uncertainty about the gender of one or both.  It would be great if we could abandon gendered pronouns altogether, as the much needed pursuit of gender equality has complicated our our use of pronouns in many other ways also.  “... its bone...” would have been fine if Jake and Janet had been dogs:  why not humans too?

Well, we are not quite ready for that.  So “his or her’ will do, or, at a stretch, “...his/her...”, but “...their...” is the one with social momentum, I think.